# How can I solve the error "Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor m cannot be invoked without 'new'" when trying to view a polymer v2.0 app

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

How can I solve the following error when trying to access a polymer v 2.0 app on ios' safari?

> Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor m cannot be invoked without
>   'new' from custom-elements-es5-adaptor.

Running the the polymer v2.0 starter kit works fine in chrome, it however throws the above error when trying it for ios.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#custom-elements-es5-adapterjs

According to the spec, Custom Elements must be ES6 classes (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#custom-element-conformance). Since most projects need to support a wide range of browsers that don't necessary support ES6, it may make sense to compile your project to ES5. However, ES5-style custom element classes will not work with native Custom Elements because ES5-style classes cannot properly extend ES6 classes, like HTMLElement.

To work around this, load custom-elements-es5-adapter.js before declaring new Custom Elements.

Comment: I'm having this error running polymer serve in chrome. It works fine in the normal view, but it throws this error when I activate the Device Toolbar. It isn't the same reason, right?

Comment: Ok, I found in [this page](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/es6) that the recommendation for using DevTools is to serve not compiling with `polymer serve --compile never`. The problem is when my element is inside a `dom-repeat`, the same problem comes back.